# SQL Server 2008 on Node.js with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new here !

I'm trying to do a query on a MS SQL Server2008 with sequelize, but I get this error:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Invalid column name 'id'.
>       at Query.formatError (C:\xampp\htdocs\Lavori\Bit_Sense\API_BS\node_modules\s
>   equelize\lib\dialects\mssql\query.js:217:10)
>       at Request.userCallback (C:\xampp\htdocs\Lavori\Bit_Sense\API_BS\node_module
>   s\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\query.js:66:25)
>       at Request.callback (C:\xampp\htdocs\Lavori\Bit_Sense\API_BS\node_modules\te
>   dious\lib\request.js:30:27)
>       at Connection.STATE.SENT_CLIENT_REQUEST.events.message (C:\xampp\htdocs\Lavo
>   ri\Bit_Sense\API_BS\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:283:29)
>       at Connection.dispatchEvent (C:\xampp\htdocs\Lavori\Bit_Sense\API_BS\node_mo
>   dules\tedious\lib\connection.js:752:59)
>       at MessageIO. (C:\xampp\htdocs\Lavori\Bit_Sense\API_BS\node_modul
>   es\tedious\lib\connection.js:685:22)
>       at MessageIO.emit (events.js:104:17)
>       at MessageIO.eventData (C:\xampp\htdocs\Lavori\Bit_Sense\API_BS\node_modules
>   \tedious\lib\message-io.js:58:21)
>       at Socket. (C:\xampp\htdocs\Lavori\Bit_Sense\API_BS\node_modules\
>   tedious\lib\message-io.js:3:59)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
>       at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)

I've installed this module:
- sequelize ;
- tedious ;

I haven't problem on the connection, only with this query:

```js
db.KEY_ARTI.findAll({
  where:{
       CACODICE: cacodice
     }
 }).then(function(data) {
  res.send(data);
 });
```

What can I do ? I haven't ANY column called id

Here is my table:

```js
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var settings = global.settings.databases.DATABASE;
var errors = global.errors;
var utilities = global.utilities; 

var sequelize = new Sequelize(settings.schema, settings.username, settings.password, {
      dialect: settings.dialect,
      host: settings.host,
   port: settings.port, /* BISOGNA USARE LA DYNAMIC PORT */
      logging: function (str) {
          if(settings.log)
            console.log("querylog: "+str.replace("Executing (default):", "") );
      },
    });

sequelize.authenticate().then(function(err) {
    if (!!err) {
      console.log('Database '+settings.schema+' Connection Error:', err)
    } 
    else {
      console.log('Database '+settings.schema+' Connected')
    }
});

exports.sequelize = sequelize;

/*
 * KEY_ARTI
 */
exports.KEY_ARTI = sequelize.define('KEY_ARTI', {
 CACODICE: Sequelize.CHAR(20),
 CADESART: Sequelize.CHAR(40),
}
```

Comment: Can you post your initializing code as well?

Comment: here it's saying in Invalid column name 'id'. Can you check about this. Or post the code for review.

Comment: I added in the answer the code, and I'm sure that I have the Object, because if I do a console.log(db.KEY_ARTI) and isn't undefined or null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, sequelize will add a primary key called id, if you don't do anything yourself.

```
sequelize.define('model', {}); // Adds an id key

sequelize.define('model', {
  name: {
    primaryKey: true
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
}); // Doesn't add an id, because you already marked another column as primary key
```

It is also possible to have a model without a primary key, but I wouldn't recommend this

Comment: Yes I find it !

I added the primary key, but, as you said, you can remove the attributes